# How to skip building the Apk when modifying the unit test in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

Every time I modify my unit tests, my apk is built again even when there are no app side changes. This is inline with the documentation below but it significantly impacts my productivity

> The Android Plugin for Gradle compiles the local unit test code located in the default directory (src/test/java/), builds a test app, and executes it locally using the default test runner class. Android Studio then displays the results in the Run window.

How can I avoid building the apk during this process to boost up my productivity?

Comment: Are you sure a rebuild takes place and not just a check if it is up to date?

Comment: Yes. I am sure.